# Eccodes grib_copy - How to identify the levels and parameters?

Tags: raster, grib-2

I would like to generate a grib from a full GFS grib2 having, for example, only the U and V component for 850 hPa. To do so, I've seen I could use the eccodes library or the command line grib_copy but I don't find how to filter the parameters. Usually in GDAL I use the band numbers but with eccodes I've no idea where to start.

Do you have any reference that tells me how to get the parameters? Or maybe another way to do it?

In the grib_copy documentation I couldn't find (https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/grib_copy)

Answer (score -2):

grib_copy -w shortName=u/v,level=850 full_file.grib out_file.grib

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Thank you for your answer!  A good answer should include not only the solution, but an explanation as to how/where to use the suggested answer, but also what it does and how it solves the question.  Please [edit] your answer to expand to include this explanation.